# Firefox SVG transform-origin fix ruins another part of my animation

Tags: css, svg

My animation was broken in Firefox and the answer to get it working was:

```
svg * { transform-box: fill-box; }
```

However, the fix also broke a working part of my CSS animation. I tried removing the styling like so, which doesn't work:

```
#eye * { transform-box: none; }
```

SVG section it is ruining:

```
<g id="eye">
  <path ...>
  <ellipse ...>
</g>
```

How do you override the transform-box fix for a specific element?

Comment: Add a snippet that can demonstrate the problem. Without the code, it's hard to visualize what is going on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give the element(s) in the SVG that needs fixing a class and then specify that in the CSS instead of applying the `transform-box: fill-box` as a global for the whole SVG

```
<svg>
  <g id="eye">
      <path ...>
      <ellipse ...>
  </g>
  <g class="brokenElement">
      <path ...>
      <ellipse ...>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Then in the CSS

```
.brokenElement { transform-box: fill-box; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Jack had a working answer to not apply the fix globally, instead, target the SVG shapes that need the fix with a class. I stuck with the global fix, because it fixed 6 shape animations, and messed up only one. I then reverted back with "transform-box:view-box".

```
svg * { transform-box: fill-box; }
svg #pig-eye * {transform-box: view-box;}
```

I found the info here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-box